# Need the logic to find the value of one column for the min of another column in same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, date, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

i written the below code to get like this

```
SELECT `temp2`.`UserId` AS `UserId`,
              `temp2`.`ScheduleDate` AS `ScheduleDate`,
             `temp2`.`daystodue`
  FROM (
SELECT
      `temp1`.`UserId` AS `UserId`,
      `temp1`.`ScheduleDate` AS `ScheduleDate`,
      `temp1`.`DueDate` AS `DueDate`,
      `temp1`.`CompletedState` AS `CompletedState`,
      IF(((`temp1`.`CompletedState` = 0) AND ((`temp1`.`ScheduleDate` - CURDATE()) <= 0)), (TO_DAYS(`temp1`.`DueDate`) - TO_DAYS(CURDATE())), 0) AS `daystodue`
    FROM (SELECT
        `fd_dw`.`ComplianceFactTable`.`UserId` AS `UserId`,
        CAST(`fd_dw`.`ComplianceFactTable`.`CourseModule_ScheduleDateID` AS date) AS `ScheduleDate`,
        CAST(`fd_dw`.`ComplianceFactTable`.`CourseModule_dueDateID` AS date) AS `DueDate`,
        `fd_dw`.`ComplianceFactTable`.`CourseModuleComplete_completionstate` AS `CompletedState`
      FROM `fd_dw`.`ComplianceFactTable`
      WHERE ((`fd_dw`.`ComplianceFactTable`.`CourseModule_dueDateID` > 0)
      AND ((CAST(`fd_dw`.`ComplianceFactTable`.`CourseModule_dueDateID` AS date) - CURDATE()) > 0))) `temp1`) `temp2` 
  WHERE `temp2`.`UserId` IN (223699,223741,223780,223678,243988,380316,388737,121896,491562)
```

I got this output when i executed the above query

```
ID       Date      value
121896  2019-12-06  0
121896  2019-11-06  0
121896  2020-01-06  0
223678  2019-12-23  0
223678  2019-11-23  0
223678  2020-01-23  0
223678  2019-10-23  43
223699  2019-12-23  0
223699  2019-11-23  0
223699  2020-01-23  0
223699  2019-10-23  43
223741  2019-12-23  0
223741  2019-11-23  0
223741  2020-01-23  0
223741  2019-10-23  43
223780  2019-12-23  0
223780  2019-11-23  0
223780  2020-01-23  0
223780  2019-10-23  43
243988  2019-10-15  21
243988  2020-01-15  0
243988  2019-12-15  0
380316  2019-10-05  0
380316  2019-11-05  0
380316  2019-12-05  0
380316  2020-01-05  0
388737  2019-10-23  29
388737  2019-11-23  0
388737  2020-01-23  0
388737  2019-12-23  0
491562  2019-10-17  7
491562  2019-10-17  7
491562  2019-10-17  23
491562  2019-11-17  0
491562  2019-12-17  0
491562  2020-01-17  0
491562  2019-10-17  7
491562  2019-10-17  7
```

but i want something like this

```
121896  2019-11-06  0
223678  2019-10-23  43
223699  2019-10-23  43
223741  2019-10-23  43
223780  2019-10-23  43
243988  2019-10-15  21
380316  2019-10-05  0
388737  2019-10-23  29
491562  2019-10-17  7
```

Comment: Explain the logic for that output. Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what is your mysql version?

Comment: Where is the code you are referring to?

Comment: `SELECT Col1, min(Col2), min(Col3) from table group by Col1`

Comment: The logic is for each user, for the minimum date field i want the corresponding value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that, for each id, you want to record with the minimum date. When there are multiple records with the minimum date, you want the one with the minimm date.

In MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select id, date, value
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by id order by date, value) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated suquery for filtering:

```
select id, date, min(value) value
from mytable t
where t.date = (
    select t1.date from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id order by t1.date, t1.value limit 1
)
group by id, date
```

Or:

```
select id, date, min(value) value
from mytable t
where t.date = (select min(t1.date) from mytable t1 where t1.id = t.id)
group by id, date
```

In this **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hrHcCooYkuocsbbV8rEYCm/1)**, all 3 queries return:

```
| id     | date       | value |
| ------ | ---------- | ----- |
| 121896 | 2019-11-06 | 0     |
| 223678 | 2019-10-23 | 43    |
| 223699 | 2019-10-23 | 43    |
| 223741 | 2019-10-23 | 43    |
| 223780 | 2019-10-23 | 43    |
| 243988 | 2019-10-15 | 21    |
| 380316 | 2019-10-05 | 0     |
| 388737 | 2019-10-23 | 29    |
| 491562 | 2019-10-17 | 7     |
```

Comment: You should have one row for id, and not sure if want min for each col or just the data related to min date

Comment: i want the value(third column) related to the min date

Comment: I think min(date) is cleaner.

Comment: Thanks Juan!! can you help me with only single record for each user

Comment: @Sai: where there are multiple records for the minimum date, which one do you want to show?

Comment: if we more than one value for a single date , then i want only the minimum of those values like
491562 2019-10-17  7

Comment: OK. Are you using MySQL 8.0 or a lower version?

Comment: i am using lower version

Comment: What is the problem. The last query work with lower versions. did you try?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: there are ties in lower dates, they want a single record per ties.

Comment: Thanks @GMB. I will try and get back to you guys

Comment: Thank you for your help! Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Select min(column1), min(column2) from yourtablename

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have mysql 8 use a correlated query

```
  SELECT *
  FROM yourTable t1
  WHERE date = (SELECT MIN(date)
                FROM yourTable t2
                WHERE t1.user_id = t2.user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output is different than the title of your question, because it contains for each of the values of the 1st column the row with the minimum value in the 2nd column (date).
Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where id = t.id and date < t.date
)
```